# Put request python flask

Tags: python, json, flask, put

I'm working on a `PUT` request to be able to modify data in my JSON file, using Flask and Python. The problem is it won't save the changes made.

Below is my code:

```
@app.route('/updated', methods = ['POST', 'PUT' 'GET'])
def update():
    try:
        title = request.form['title']
        print title

        if request.method == 'POST':
            with open("articles.json", 'r+') as json_File:
                articles = json.load(json_File)
                for article in articles['article']:
                    if title == article['title']:
                        print article['title']
                        print article['author']
                        print article['article_id']
                        article['title'] = title
                        article['author'] = request.form['author']
                        article['text'] = request.form['text']
                        article['article_id'] = request.form['article_id']
                        print article
                        save_article = json.dumps(article, json_File)
                    else:
                        print "article could not be added"
                #json_File.close()
                return render_template('updated.html', save_article = save_article, article = article)

    except:
        print "This didn't work."
        return render_template('errorHandler.html'), 404
```

Comment: Your question says you are working on a `PUT` request, but the code block is looking for a `POST` method.

Comment: I would get the error messages 500 and 404 if I put the PUT request in the if statement.

Answer (score 4):

Example from (http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html)

```
@app.route('/echo', methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def api_echo():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "ECHO: GET\n"

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return "ECHO: POST\n"

    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        return "ECHO: PACTH\n"

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        return "ECHO: PUT\n"

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        return "ECHO: DELETE"
```

Probably best to have a if/elif/else for each method in the decorator, prevents weird bug and edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this part:

```
if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT':
```

For better practices, i think you should do:

```
if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT':
     # do your code here, which edit into your database
if request.method == 'GET':
     # do GET code here, which return data from your database
```

Or separate your https methods into different functions

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) "dumps" to a string, not a file. So

```
save_article = json.dumps(article, json_File)
```

will return a string which is then bound to the `save_article` variable, but the file is not actually modified. You probably meant to use [`json.dump(article, json_File)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) which does accept a file as the second argument.

Note: The file argument is silently ignored in Python 2, which I assume that you are using because it would show up as an error in Python 3.

---

There might be other problems. One is that articles will be *appended* to the file, but it would seem that the intention of the code is to *update* an existing article. It's generally impractical to update text files in place. A better method would be to iterate over the articles, updating those that match the title. Then *rewrite* the whole file once at the end. Here's an example:

```
        with open("articles.json", 'r') as json_File:
            articles = json.load(json_File)

        # update any matching articles
        for article in articles['article']:
            if title == article['title']:
                article['author'] = request.form['author']
                article['text'] = request.form['text']
                article['article_id'] = request.form['article_id']

        # rewrite the whole JSON file with updated dictionary
        with open("articles.json", 'w') as json_File:
            json.dump(articles, json_File)
```

As you are updating the article data you might want to consider using a simple database to manage it. You could take a look at [Flask SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/).

Comment: Could you show me an example how to update an article instead of the whole file?

Comment: @Angelica_92-: my point is that you need to rewrite the whole file because it is difficult to update a file in place. I have provided an example of how to do that above.

Comment: Thank you for the example! I can now change the value temporarily, however the change isn't saved.

Comment: What is `articles['article']`? Is it a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Yes exactly. Maybe I've done it wrong, but it is supposed to be a key value dictionary.